# What regular expression will select all lines that have more than one punctuation mark?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this regular expression:

```
\..*?\.
```

But it only selects between two periods, not every punctuation mark, and it also selects across multiple lines.
Would modifying this expression to only take in one line at a time work somehow, if there's also a way to group punctuation into where we have a period?
Just to make things simpler, at this time I only need the expression to recognize periods, exclamation points, and question marks. I don't need it to register commas.

Thanks to Nathan and Agumander below, I know to substitute [.!?] in place of \. now, but I'm still having trouble with the other half of my question.
Just to make sure I'm being more clear, using [.!?].*?[.!?]\s will highlight text between punctuation marks, but across multiple lines. So I can't use it to bookmark only the lines that have multiple punctuation marks.

Comment: I think you're looking for `[\.!?]` this will get any character that is a period, exclamation point, or question mark.

Comment: Why does this select across multiple lines? The `.` character usually excludes newlines, except if you use some modifier.

Comment: @Nathan: What's that backslash for?

Comment: @Lightness: It's slashing the period to ensure the regex engine picks it up as a literal period instead of the meaning of 'any character'. Since it's within the square brackets, it's not required and has the same effect as using `[.?!]`. It's more of a preference since they both are equal. IMO, the slash makes it more explicit of the intention.

Comment: @Nathan: Sure, to someone who doesn't know how to read regexes, or is accustomed to reading them incorrectly.

Comment: @Lightness: Wouldn't it be more helpful to show me why I'm wrong? If there's no difference in the execution and no speed efficiency gains. Why would you say my method is incorrect? It seems to be purely preferential than technical. If there's truly a difference, let me know so I don't keep making the same mistake. Otherwise, just accept there's more than one way to solve the problem.

Comment: @Nathan: When did I say you're wrong? Or that I cannot accept there is more than one way to solve the problem? Please refrain from putting words into my mouth. Thanks.

Comment: @Lightness: Then let me apologize, from your statement it appears like you're saying that people who do as I do lack the ability to read regexes. I was just trying to understand why.

Comment: @Nathan: No I'm saying that the only possible audience for whom `[\.!?]` expresses intent better than `[.!?]` are those who lack the ability to read regexes. I wasn't saying that you do. Yes, the choice a matter of opinion. I think my particular opinion on this is clear by now, though.

Comment: @Lightness: Thanks for the clarification. I do agree with you, now that I understand what you're saying. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Nathan: Yes, you along with Agumander have given me the correct modification for period to multiple punctuations, but I'm still having trouble with the regex not breaking the search for each new line.

Answer (score 2):

Placing characters inside a pair of square brackets will match to any of the enclosed characters. In your case you'd want `[.?!]`

If you want to match any sentence that has two of these, then you'll be looking for a pair of `[.!?]` separated by zero or more of any character.

The regex that matches strings with more than one of the set `[.?!]` would then be `[.!?].*[.!?]`

To make `.` match newlines, you'd add the `s` modifier to your regex.

...so the full regex would be `/[.!?].*[.!?]/s`

Comment: I'm not sure on the forward/backward slash usage across every regex enabled script, but when I entered \\[.!?].*[.!?]\s notepad++ just bookmarked the first line that has a period, then pink marked the whole document to the second to last period. On the other hand, [.!?].*?[.!?]\s selects the text between punctuation (and bookmarks the line) but doesn't break per line. It will still bookmark a line that has one punctuation mark to select that one punctuation mark along with the punctuation mark on the next line. I need a way to break [.!?].*?[.!?]\s so that it will stop matching multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. Thanks to Agumander and Nathan above I substituted [.!?] in for the two \. in my original regex:

\..*?\. became [.!?].*[.!?]

Putting \s at the end of the regex made it pink select the entire document in notepad++.
The last issue I had was remembering to turn off "matches newline."

Answer (score 0):

Agumander, I think you're asking for a regex that basically finds multiple punctuation marks on a single line. So here's one way to do it.

Here's the text I'm going to match. The regex will match the first line in it's entirety, but will not match the second.

```
Here's a line with multiple punctuation. The entire line will match the regex!
This line does not have multiple punctuation.
```

**Regex**

```
^.*(?:[\.?!].*){2,}$
```

**Explanation**

```
^            -- Start matching at the beginning of a line
.*           -- match any character 0 or more times
(?:          -- start a new non-capturing group
   [.?!]     -- find a character matching a period, question mark, or exclamation point.
   .*        -- match any character 0 or more times
 )           
 {2,}        -- repeat the previous group 2 or more times. This is how we ensure there's at least two punctuation marks before considering it a match.
 $           -- end of line anchor, basically stop matching at the end of a line
```